# How can I define T in this linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

For $T: V2\to V2$

$T$ maps each point with polar coordinate $(r,\theta)$ to each point with polar coordinate

$(r,2\theta)$ and $T$ maps $0$ onto itself.

I let  $r= \sqrt{ x^2 + y^2}$ and $\theta=\arctan(y/x)$ and tried to find function of $T$

but I failed.

can anybody please tell me how to define $T$ ?

Comment: $r$ is the distance of the point from the origin and $\theta$ is the angle the point makes over the $x$-axis. So this map isn't changing the distance of any point, but it is rotating it.

Answer (score 0):

$T$ is the rotation by the angle $\theta$ and if we identify $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb C$ then $T$ is defined by
$$T:\Bbb C\to \Bbb C,\quad z\mapsto ze^{i\theta}$$
so with $z=x+iy$ we have $ze^{i\theta}=x\cos\theta-y\sin\theta+i(x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta) $ hence

$$T:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R^2,\quad (x,y)\mapsto (x\cos\theta-y\sin\theta,x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta)$$

Comment: I think the person who asked the question was looking for $T:z \mapsto z^2/|z|$.

Comment: This is just wrong. For a number $z$ on the positive real axis we have $\theta=0$, so $2\theta=\theta=0$ and $T(z)=z$.